# I need to create a list of users from a text file

Tags: python, list, text

I have a text file of data. It looks like this but with a few hundred lines.

```
Test: 0
AssignentDone
UserDone
johndoe
Assignment8
Resp: YES
Trade: YES
Journal: YES
```

I need to build a list of the user names. The data under each person is all disorganized, but at the end of each person's data is the line "UserDone" and then the very next line is the name of a new user.

I have this

```
def get_names( file ):
    with open("userdata.txt", "rt") as file:
        for line in file:
            if "UserDone" in line:
                students= list(file.readlines()[1])`
```

When I run this I get

```
ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data
```

Is there any way I can get python to recognize the "UserDone" line and then add the very next line to a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use file iteration and readline or you make a mess, and python is kind enought to let you know. Try something like the following (I'm sure it can be done in a smarter way)

```
def get_names( file ):
    savenext = False
    with open("userdata.txt", "rt") as file:
        for line in file:
            if savenext == True:
                students= line
                savenext == False

            if "UserDone" in line:
                savenext = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps look at the .split function? http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Or the Regular expressions module: http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html